# Reading epub file in titanium studio iPhone

Tags: iphone, titanium-mobile, epub, filereader

Hi I'm developing an iPHone app using Titanium Studio in which I would like to read .epub file. I googled and could not find any good reference. Can any body direct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the Appcelerator market place for plugins?

Comment: Yes. But I didn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

Use a epub like a zip file, extract the content of the epub in your device and readit with webview from Appcelerator.